# Context module not changing page title tag

Tags: 7, meta-tags

Issue is, that in my case Context module isn't changing `<title>` tag of the page.

I've configured Context module to change Meta tags (title and meta description) for specific view pages of my site for specific language.

I have two conditions:

1. Language
2. Path

and one reaction:

1. Meta data

This Context module has changed meta description, but title tag hasn't changed, it shows default value.

Is there some kind of a tweak to get it working properly? Or am I doing something wrong?